How to get rid of the sign-in prompt for Microsoft Office 365?
Every time I open one of the Office 365 applications on my personal Windows 10 desktop, I get this sign-in prompt.
I'm already signed into Office 365 with my personal Microsoft account. This pop-up started launching, after I attempted to log into my organization's 365 account.
I already tried reinstalling Office, but no joy.  How do I get this log-in prompt to go away for good?


You may refer to this thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/unwanted-office-365-sign-in-prompts/b1202be2-fa0b-4b2a-b992-902c3487df58?page=1, clear the work account information, then sign in back for a check.

Thanks @Emily.  I tried all the suggestions in that thread, but the problem sadly persists.

Your organisation account and your personal Microsoft account are two different things. If you want to access documents from your organisation, you will need to authenticate with your work account. That's just basic Microsoft security at work, ensuring you are authorised to access these documents.
Your organisation's documents can be in different locations, e.g. Cloud-based in SharePoint, OneDrive (for business), or Teams. You may also have syncronised documents to your local computer with the OneDrive or SharePoint sync features. While these documents now appear local, you still need to authenticate with your work account, because any changes in the synced files will be written back to the cloud storage.
In Word or other Office desktop apps, you can go to File > Account and see which account is currently signed in to the Office application. You can also add connected services, which helps reduce the number of times you need to sign in.
In the following screenshot you can see

the account currently signed in - for me that is my work account
my personal OneDrive service - which is synced to my local drive
my work OneDrive for Business service, which is also synced to my local drive
my work SharePoint locations, which are only in the cloud

With this setting, I can access all files on my PC and on my employer's cloud storage and don't have to sign in all the time.
If I switch accounts to my personal Microsoft account, I don't have access to the cloud files.


Thanks for the detailed response.  Unfortunately, I only see my personal account info under File >> Account.
